# How to call a Java function on an object from C++ from a separate thread

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

Okay I can't quite get this to work. I'm on Android and using JNI to start up a large amount of c++ code. I want to send a single string back to the Main Activity so I can display it on screen but I keep getting jammed. After a lot of work I did figure out that I needed to attach my current thread first because my jvm pointer wasn't valid. But now I can't figure out how to use my jobject for MainActivity from this new thread.

So to start off the c++ code I do this:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_myname_mydetails_myfunction_MainActivity_startItUp(
    JNIEnv* env,
    _jobject *jobjecte /* this */) {

//trying to store the JVM
jint err = env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);
//start the cameras up starting with camera 1
startThings(jvm, jobjecte, env);

//return a the Starting Cameras String for the java UI
return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

I pass these points into my c++ object with this function

```
void setJVM( JavaVM *_jvm, _jobject *_mainActivity, JNIEnv* _env){
    jvm = _jvm;
    mainActivity = _mainActivity;
    env = _env;
}
```

Now in my thread in c++ land.

```
void myclass::mymethod(int64_t _profile){
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    JavaVMAttachArgs args;
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; // choose your JNI version
    args.name = NULL; // you might want to give the java thread a name
    args.group = NULL; // you might want to assign the java thread to a ThreadGroup
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, &args);
    jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(mainActivity);
```

When I call mymethod from a thread I get: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject. So okay fair, I'd guess that if the JVM pointer is not the same across threads then the jobject pointer isn't either. But then how do I get that pointer to my Main Activity object to call my java function?

Comment: Doesn't show `startThings` and the error may not necessary be due to your thread. You need to also check if `AttachCurrentThread` returned `JNI_OK`

Comment: Oh sorry I was trying to keep the example clean startthings calls a method that just calls  setJVM. And yes AttachCurrentThread returns 0.

Comment: One other interesting thing is my GetObjectClass works fine if I call it right after setJVM in the main thread. But it will not work from my thread, nor from an Android asynchronous callback like onCapture complete for the camera.

Comment: The reason I asked for you to add more code is because I see you saving `_mainActivity` and I don't see any code that passes the variable to that function. However, if you did NOT use `_mainActivity = env->NewGlobalRef(mainActivity);`, then this is why you are getting invalid object errors.. You can only store objects as `global` references and delete them later (cleanup) with `env->DeleteGlobalRef(_mainActivity);`.. Likewise for `local` references. Without more code, I can't know for sure, but it's a hypothesis as to the problem, given the error and the code posted at the time of writing this

Comment: @Brandon this was indeed the problem. I had misunderstood the purpose of NewGlobalRef. I thought that it was to get a new ref in my thread. But your comment made me see it is more to save the variable in preparation to use it later.  Thank you for sticking with me on this one!  I'm happy to solve this late on a Friday.  If you feel like making this an answer later I'll come back to accept and vote for it.

Comment: You may want to consider using a tool like JavaCPP that abstracts away all those details: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to store an Java Object in native code, you need to store a `global` reference to it. To convert a `local` reference to a global reference, you need to call `env->NewGlobalRef(local_object);`

This will return you a global object reference that you can now use anywhere you want. Later on, when you're finished using the object, you need to clean it up using `env->DeleteGlobalRef(global_object);`. If you don't, the object will never be garbage collected by the JVM.

Likewise, it is a good habit to do `env->DeleteLocalRef(local_object)` too. Like for example, if you did:

```cpp
void execute_some_code() {

    jclass local_class = env->FindClass(....);
    jobject local_object = env->CallObjectMethod(....);

    _my_object = env->NewGlobalRef(local_object);

    // MUST cleanup local references since these references were not given to you by the JVM, but rather created by you in native code.

    env->DeleteLocalRef(local_object);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(local_class);

}
```

Now to solve your problem, store the object as a `global` reference as described above. Then you can access it on any `Attached` thread. Don't forget to `detach` the thread before the thread dies (otherwise attach it as a daemon if it will always be running).

```cpp
void startThings(JVM* jvm, jobject* jobject, JNIEnv* env) {

    setJVM(jvm, env->NewGlobalRef(jobject), env);

    // Possible other code
    std::thread([]{
        JNIEnv* local_env = NULL;
        JavaVMAttachArgs args = {....};
    
        int err = _jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&local_env, &args);
        if (err != JNI_OK) {
            return;
        }

        // Do stuff with _mainActivity

        // Some time later in your application:
        local_env->DeleteGlobalRef(_mainActivity);
        _jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
    }).detach();
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_myname_mydetails_myfunction_MainActivity_startItUp(
    JNIEnv* env,
    _jobject *jobject /* this */) {

    jint err = env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);
    
    startThings(jvm, jobject, env);

    // Optional here but a good habit to know how it works
    env->DeleteLocalRef(jobject);

    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

If you are using C++11, you can actually use `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter to handle all the memory management like deleting the global refs :)

Comment: Very good, but he coud also use `WeakGlobalRef` if he doesn't mind re-acquiring the object when the weak reference disappears.